# How to link to other webpage based on input in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I basically have a React App in which it chooses whether you are male and female
If you are are male it link to a webpage In case Of Female it links to other webpage
But in React I am not able to do so

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Router , Route , browserHistory , Link} from 'react-router'
import Card from './Card.js'
class App extends Component {

constructor(){
  super();
this.state = {
  options : 'none',
  male : false
}

}

  setGender = (event)=>{
    let gender = event.target.value;
   if(gender === 'MALE'){
     this.setState({options : 'male'})

   }else if(gender === 'FEMALE'){
     this.setState({options : 'female'})

   }
   else{
     console.log('not selected')
   }
 }

 optionsSelected = (event)=>{
  if(this.state.options === 'male'){
    console.log('yes it is male');
    console.log(event)

this.setState({male : true});
  }else if(this.state.options === 'female'){
    console.log('yes it is female');

// Not understanding what to do here to link to a page 

  }else{
    console.log('not selected');
  }

 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

    <input type="submit" onClick={event => this.optionsSelected(event)}/>

      <div onChange={event => this.setGender(event)}>
            <input type="radio" value="MALE" name="gender"/> Male
            <input type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="gender"/> Female
          </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Can I do this browserHistory.push("/path-to-link"); – Zaid just now   edit

please dont downvote because I might get blocked

Comment: Could you indent/format your code, please.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `link to a webpage`, have you configured your router and you need to navigate to another Route

Comment: You can use space or tab.

Comment: + Shubham Can you elaborate please I am new to this please

Comment: + Pedro Ok let me do it

Comment: You can redirect to another page with: window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"

Comment: If you want to Route to another page, you'll need to use React Router. Documentation is here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy First install it in your package.json file and from there, you'll need to import the modules in your ReactJS file.

Comment: Thanks so much Petro but is there any react specific way of doing this???

Comment: Thanks Curious13 but I want to change path based on gender

Comment: Can I do this browserHistory.push("/path-to-link");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
optionsSelected = (event) => {
    if (this.state.options !== 'none') {
        // redirect to male or female website
        window.location.href = this.state.options === 'male' ? 'http://male.xyz' : 'http://female.xyz';
    } else {
        // show error msg or do other stuff ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please answer it

Comment: @Zaid - If you wanna redirect to another page that is not in your server, this way seems to solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by server?

Comment: In my opinion this is the react-way (vanilla javascript). If you want to "route" to another page in your own app, sure there is (react-router redirect), but than you will redirect to another route/component.

Comment: I guess by using browserHistory.push("/path-to-link"); Is it coorect??

Comment: If you're using react-router v4.0  you can use `this.props.history.push(this.state.options === 'male' ? 'http://male.xyz' : 'http://female.xyz`)`

Comment: I'm going to make a second comment repeating myself because I got locked out of editing my comment.  I accidentally used a ` instead of a ' in my comment.  The right code would use: 
`this.props.history.push(this.state.options === 'male' ? 'http://male.xyz' : 'http://female.xyz')`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response btw I was making a quiz app